# How to make UITableView row as wide as the label in it dynamically?

Tags: objective-c, ios, uitableview

I have a UITableView where each row may have a label anywhere from no lines to any number of lines (realistically 3-4). I am wanting the row to be expanded based on the UILabelView contents.

I have this so far:

```
- (CGFloat) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    CGFloat  height        = 60.0;

UIFont *font        = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica-BoldOblique" size:10.0];
NSString *text      = reminder.notes; //the text that will be in the UiLabelView
CGFloat notesHeight = [text sizeWithFont:font
                               constrainedToSize:CGSizeMake(250.0, 4000.0)
                                   lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeTailTruncation].height;

height += notesHeight;

return height;

}
```

I still get screwy results. What can I do to accomplish my goal?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are using `UILineBreakModeTailTruncation` as lineBreakMode which will always result in a single line and `sizeWithFont:constrainedToSize:lineBreakMode:` will then return the needed size of that single line.

Try `UILineBreakModeWordWrap` instead.

**edit:** I hope you have set the `numberOfLines`-property of a `UILabel` to `0` (zero) so that your label is able to draw many lines.